# InfluxDB: max-series-per-database incorrect error

Tags: influxdb

When trying to put some date into InfluxDB (1.7.3) I am getting error that `max-series-per-database` is reached:

> (“error”:“partial write: max-series-per-database limit exceeded: (1000000) dropped=2")

Meanwhile `show series exact cardinality` for specific database shows that there are just around 510 000 entries.
Also `select count(*) from database` gives same result

Any idea I am getting error that max series per database is reached?

upd:
I am using open source version of InfluxDB without clustering
`show series cardinality` show almost the same result what exact cardinality does

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing max-series-per-database configuration option and see if the error persists.

If you are using enterprise clustering, the exact cardinality may only count series on one region server, while another has the rest 490k series.

Are there other retention policies in the same database?

Also note, that error may be generated based on approximate cardinality.

Comment: I am using open source version which doesn't have clustering  
Approximate cardinality is very similar to exact cardinality (~510k entries)  
I have two retention policies:  
`name      duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----      -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen   0s       168h0m0s           1        false
two_weeks 336h0m0s 24h0m0s            1        true`